# React cannot render "Login" component on redirecting unauthorized users

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router-dom

i would like to redirect unauthenticated users to the Login page but the router is not rendering the `Login` Component. I cannot tell what is wrong with my code.
Below is a test out code i am using.

```
import React, { Component, Suspense } from "react";
 import { Route, Switch, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
 import { connect } from "react-redux";
 import Fulllayout from '../layouts/fulllayout';
 import Login from "./auth/login";
 const RestrictedRoute = ({ component: Component, currentUrl, authUser, ...rest }) => {
 // const isTokenValid = authUser && jwtDecode(authUser.auth_token).exp > Date.now / 1000;
 const isTokenValid = false;
 return (
    <Route
        {...rest}
        render={
            props => isTokenValid ?
                (<Component exact {...props} />)
                : (
                    <Redirect
                        to={{ pathname: "/login", state: { from: currentUrl }}}
                    />
                )}/>
  )
 }
 class App extends Component {
 render() {
    let pathname = this.props.location.pathname;
    if (this.props.location.pathname === "/login") {
        pathname = "/"
    }
    return (
        <Switch>
            <RestrictedRoute
                currentUrl={pathname}
                authUser={"Userauth"}
                path="/"
                component={Fulllayout}
            />
            <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
        </Switch>
    );
   }}
  const mapStateToProps = ({ router }) => {
  const { location } = router;
  return { location };
  }
  export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App)
```

It changes the route properly to `/login` but cannot render the Component.
Below is the `main.js`

```
   import React from 'react';
   import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
   import { ConnectedRouter } from 'connected-react-router';
   import store, { history } from "./store";
   import App from "./views"
   const MainApp = () => {
   return (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
            <App />
        </ConnectedRouter>
    </Provider>
   )}
  export default MainApp;
```

Thanks for you help in advance....

Answer (score 1):

first, you should wrap `Switch` inside `Router`

```
//BrowserRouter it just one of the routers provided by react-router
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

 return (
      <Router>
        <Switch>
           ...
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    );
```

second, you have an issue with the way you want to obtain `props.location`, you should do something like that

```
import { compose } from 'redux'
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

class App extends Component {
 render() {
  console.log(this.props.location && this.props.location.pathname)
  ...rest render...
 }
}

export default compose(withRouter, connect(mapStateToProps))(App)
```

Comment: I think "composer" is exported from "redux" not "react-redux"